# How to differentiate between a response and a request in a call method within Rack Middleware?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, middleware, rack

I'm writing my first piece of Rack Middleware and if I understand correctly the call(env) method is triggered on inbound requests and outbound responses. What I don't understand is how it's possible to differentiate between a request and a response. Does this mean that call get called twice when hitting an endpoint ? Once for the request and another time for the response ?